# Table setting for Hyphothesis testing - crosstab table with t-test and WMW test

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, plotly, shinydashboard

I am trying to set a Cross table for hypothesis testing. I have divided the full sample by performing / non-performing loans. I want to tabulate the mean and median for the full sample and both sub-samples. Then I want to compare the means of the sub-sample to test if they are significantly different with a t-test and [WMW test][1]. How can I code that in Python? Finale outcome should be a .csv Excel table output.

I have been working with pandas for pivot tables and crosstab. Scipy seems to offer all the statistics needed. I have had a look at plotly and dash for complex tables.

I want to tabulate the mean and median for the full sample and both sub-samples. Then I want to compare the means of the sub-sample to test if they are significantly different with a t-test and WMW test. How can I code that in Python? Finale outcome should be a .csv Excel table output.

Data columns are loan attributes from Lending Club:
- loan amount
- interest rate etc.

Target variable column "dead" -> default or non-default, separates the samples.
In total 230k observations.

Comment: Hi, please post some minimal data example and desired output. That's how you can get quick solution.

Comment: @DataPsycho : I have added some info about my data. I have made a draft for the final table.